# rails ajaxful rating rating_averate doesn't update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I impleneted ajaxful rating on a Store model with 3 dimensions. I am caching rating average for each dimension as well as the overall average rating. The individual dimension rates are being saved and shown correctly and everything works fine except, the "rating_average" does not update (still at 0) even after multiple users have updated it for a specific record.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does calling the dimensions explicitly help? Something like

```
<%= ratings_for @article, :dimensions => [:speed, :beauty, :price] %>
```

This is untested, just a suggestion!